# Using Croppie - Simple Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, cropper

I'm trying to use the image cropper, Croppie from Foliotek, but for some reason it is not working for me - And I am using a very simple example.

I am using the demo example from the following page: http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

But all I get is a blank page in my browser - Both IE and Chrome.

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <link href="croppie.css" rel="Stylesheet" />  
    <script src="croppie.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>

    <div id="demo-basic"></div>

    <script>
        var basic = $('#demo-basic').croppie({
            viewport: {
                width: 150,
                height: 200
            }
        });
        basic.croppie('bind', {
            url: 'cat.jpg',
            points: [77, 469, 280, 739]
        });

    </script>
</body>  
</html>
```

I hope someone is able to help me get this image cropper working :-)

Thanks - James

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What errors do you see in your Console? Do you need jQuery for this? If so, your page is not loading it.

Comment: Investigating further, this appears to be an issue with the library itself. I can load the image alone, but not in the framework with jQuery. https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/afb76b7f/3/ and a vanilla test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/afb76b7f/4/

Answer (score 16):

The docs do not give you good examples. I found this: [Jquery plugin Croppie to crop image Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237020/jquery-plugin-croppie-to-crop-image-error)

That helped me figure a few things out.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/afb76b7f/8/

**HTML**

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="demo-basic">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#page {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#demo-basic {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var basic = $('#demo-basic').croppie({
    viewport: {
      width: 150,
      height: 200
    }
  });
  basic.croppie('bind', {
    url: 'https://i.imgur.com/xD9rzSt.jpg',
    points: [77, 469, 280, 739]
  });
});
```

So your `div` needs to have some `width` and `height`, otherwise it will render too small to see the viewport. Also, if you remove the `points: [77, 469, 280, 739]`, it will load the image full in the `div`.

Comment: but how can we use to rotate the image?

Comment: @NarendraVerma this question did not include a rotate ability, nor does this library.

Comment: Yes, That correct but do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: @NarendraVerma it could be done in a number of ways and with a number of plugins. What have you tried?

Comment: When I am running this on localhost, it is giving CORS error. What could be the reason and solution?

Comment: @HimalayaGarg you might want to review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966707/cors-error-on-same-domain

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to use the jquery librarie as mentionned in the plugin. In the head section of your html just add the call to jquery.